# Get thumbnail image of the main page of all the running process in window

Tags: wpf, window, gdi+, win32gui, aero-peek

In my app I want to enable the user to see a small thumbnail, of the main window, for all the running process (that has window).

- My app is a regular window desktop application (written in wpf)
- I don't want to bring the other processes to foreground before getting the thumbnails
- It will be nice if most of the code will be written in .net with PInvoke (if needed) but native is o.k also

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using DWM I managed to capture the main window for all running process. I've used two great examples (thank a lot for that).

1. ByBart De Smet For Windows Form:

> http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/05/4495.aspx

2. For Wpf:

> http://www.11011.net/archives/000653.html